# How to avoid breaks when content textarea is updated and stored

Tags: php, html, textarea, fopen

I am using a textarea in which a user can put some content and save the content.
So a file, like `example.txt` with its content will be saved on the server. 
What happens: even if the user does not change the content, and updates it, the content of the textarea will be saved with a couple of breaks before the content.

Below the way I store the content and read it back:

```
<form class="rafform" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="editfile" value="<?php echo $dir . '/' . $file; ?>" />
    <textarea name="editcontent">
       <?php
          readfile($dir . '/' . $file); // read content of example.txt         ?> 
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="submitmodal edit btn btn-edit " value="Update" />
</form>
```

After submit, the content will be replaced

```
if( isset($_POST['editcontent']) ){
$fn = $_POST['editfile'];   

$content = stripslashes($_POST['editcontent']);
$fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
fputs($fp,$content);
fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");
echo 'Content edited!';
}
```

If start typing text on the first line, it looks like this: 
[image]

If I update this text ( so store it) and open it again, it looks like this:

[image]

So: why are there a couple of breaks and spaces before the text? (text should be start again in the left upper corner, because I did nothing change)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : 
Don't give some enter between `<textarea></textarea>`. 
And used trim function

```
str.trim();


<form class="rafform" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="editfile" value="<?php echo $dir . '/' . $file; ?>" />
    <textarea name="editcontent"><?php
          readfile($dir . '/' . $file); // read content of example.txt         ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="submitmodal edit btn btn-edit " value="Update" />
</form>

if( isset($_POST['editcontent']) ){
$fn = trim($_POST['editfile']);   

$content = stripslashes($_POST['editcontent']);
$fp = fopen($fn,"w") or die ("Error opening file in write mode!");
fputs($fp,$content);
fclose($fp) or die ("Error closing file!");
echo 'Content edited!';
}
```

Comment: I agree!  Without enter, `<textarea name="editcontent"><?php readfile($dir . '/' . $file); ?></textarea>` solves the problem. Thnx

Comment: @mudrayakatusha : Is this help your answer please tick complete.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use trim(); a PHP function
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp
To remove any whitespaces from both sides